# Show steps to compute limit

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I'm trying to use Mathematica to compute a limit, because I have no idea how to compute it by myself.

The limit should be:
$$\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\dfrac {2^{n+1}-n-2}{2^{n}}$$

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica Stack Exchange! Can you show anything you've tried? You might like to refer to the excellent documentation within Mathematica, for example on [`Limit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Limit.html). You can also use Wolfram|Alpha from within Mathematica by typing [`= =`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/example/GetFullWolframAlphaResults.html) in a new cell and entering your query in brief English as you might on the web.

Comment: `Limit[(2^(n + 1) - n - 2)/2^n, n -> \[Infinity]] === 2`.  This becomes evident when you distribute the denominator and look at the behavior of each term.

Answer (score 2):

Your limit $$\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\dfrac {2^{n+1}-n-2}{2^{n}}=2$$ may be decomposed into the sum: $$\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\dfrac {2^{n+1}-n-2}{2^{n}}=\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\dfrac {2^{n+1}}{2^{n}}-\dfrac {n}{2^{n}}-\dfrac {2}{2^{n}}=2-0-0=2$$
And each limit:
$$\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\dfrac {2^{n+1}}{2^{n}}=2$$
$$\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\dfrac {n}{2^{n}}=0$$
$$\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\dfrac {2}{2^{n}}=0$$